# Error: `Header` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`

Tags: react-native

I am not importing Header anywhere in my code.
I am using expo with React Native and even tried switching to the Bare Workflow but no luck.

Comment: Does the error give you a file and line number?

Comment: recreating the expo project from scratch and copying all code to the new project resolved the issue.
Was probably caused due to incorrect versions which expo doesn't support.